# NodeJS conflicting with Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, ace-editor

Fairly new at webdev, used to backend.

My problem is I cannot get Ace Editor to work when the HTML page it belongs to is sent via nodeJS.  When I open the html file via a web browser, it works perfectly.  When I connect through my local host and have nodejs load the file, the html page is just plain text.

Here is my js code, very simple:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
   res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/test_ACE.html'));
}).listen(8000, function() {
   console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:8000');
});
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre id="editor">function foo(items) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i &lt; items.length; i++) {
            alert("Ace Rocks " + items[i]);
        }
    }</pre>
    <script src="src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This isn't my final html or js code, I stripped them down as bare as I could to see if I could get them to work, but even as straight forward as these are, no dice!

I hate to admit I've had this issue for almost a week and every time I revisit it I make no progress.

I'd appreciate any help, even a direction of some useful documentation.

Comment: By "just plain text" do you mean the HTML markup is shown literally or that there is just a blank page or just the pre block's text on the page (no ace editor loaded)?

Comment: @mscdex, only what is in the <pre> block is shows as plain text instead of inside an Ace editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible issue is that your node.js server doesn't serve `src-noconflict/ace.js` file.
You can see an example of working nodejs server at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/static.js#L29

Comment: So instead of sending only the 'test_ACE.html' send the whole directory?  I will try that, thank you

Comment: You may also look into using a module like [`serve-static`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#serve-files-with-vanilla-nodejs-http-server) (which is what Express has built-in) instead of manually serving up every individual file.

Comment: a_user's answer solved it, but not without the help of @mscdex being a bit more specific.  The Ace editor renders perfectly.  Now my issue is getting express to work with socket.io, but I will try that on my own.